# Use Javafx with lwjgl by swingNode and Canvas

Tags: java, swing, opengl, javafx, lwjgl

For my project in lwjgl I need javafx component. For controller and I need to use lwjgl and javafx.

I try to put lwjgl inside Pane javafx by SwingNode and (canvas in Java I swing). But I do not get the correct results. Can anyone help me?

I tried to apply this after reading previous publications on this topic.

I got this way from another post:

```
public class JavaFxLWJGL extends Application {

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
SwingNode swingnode = new SwingNode();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();

    CreateSwingNode();

    root.getChildren().add(swingnode);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1300, 1000);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    lwjgl();
}

private void CreateSwingNode() {
    JButton b = new JButton("Click Here");
    b.setBounds(600, 500, 95, 30);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 300));
    canvas.setVisible(true);

    panel.setSize(1200, 700);
    panel.add(canvas);
    panel.add(b);

    swingnode.setContent(panel);
}

public void lwjgl() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Display.setParent(canvas);
                Display.create();
            } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glOrtho(0, 1200, 300, 0, 1, -1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2i(0, 0);
                glColor3b((byte) 0, (byte) 127, (byte) 0);
                glVertex2d(640.0, 0.0);
                glColor3ub((byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255);
                glVertex2f(640.0f, 480.0f);
                glColor3d(0.0d, 0.0d, 1.0d);
                glVertex2i(0, 480);
                glEnd();
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(60);
            }
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }).start();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```